# Column to create timestamp of when a record was added

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a computed column on a table that will add a timestamp of when a record was created.

In my ingenuity I've created a column simply with "Getdate()" thinking from the moment a new record is added and the date of that moment in time recorded, it wouldn't change again.

To my dismay (obviously) the getdate() changes every millisecond... So, given my apparent absolute inability to use SQL, what do you suggest I should put in this computed column to get the timestamp?

Comment: How did you create this new column? You need to be creating a column that has a default value of `GETDATE()` (or `GETUTCDATE()`)

Comment: I've added the GETDATE() in the designer under formula for computed column specification

Comment: What you want isn't a computed column. A Computed column is a column where it's value is defined by an expression; such as `PrefixedID AS CONCAT(Prefix,'_',ID)`. What you want is a column with a `DEFAULT` value and then omit that column when you perform the `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a default value:

```
create table t (
     . . . ,
     createdAt datetime default getdate()
);
```

If you don't provide a value on `insert`, the value is given the default value -- and it would only change after that if you did an `update`.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your table :

```
 CreationDate datetime default getutcdate()
```

Answer (score 0):

You mix the computed column and the default value. Computed columns are useful based for example on one or multiple other column values.

**The default value will be the timestamp of the line insertion.
The computed column will change everytime you query the line.**

Simply add a default constraint to have the date recorded when the line is created.

```
ALTER TABLE [YourTableName]
ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [YourDateColumn];
```

Comment: That makes sense. A question related to the initial query, can I backfill data on this column for records that were already present and therefore are now blank?

Comment: Yes you definitely can. Usually the default column is here to fill a potential gap for the columns flagged as NOT NULL.